# differential equation - problem with solving

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the equation:
$y^2dx+(e^x-y)dy=0$

Do you have any idea how to solve it?
It isn't exact differential equation

Comment: it is an equation of Abel-type

Comment: What does it mean? I've never heard about it before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it as a separable equation looking for $x(y)$ instead of $y(x)$.

Define first $x=\log(z)$ which leads to $$y^2 z'-y z+z^2=0$$ Now, define $z=\frac 1u$ which leads to $$1-y \left(y u'+u\right)=0\implies y u'+u=\frac 1y$$ $$y u'+u=0\implies u=\frac C y$$ Variation of parameters $$y u'+u=\frac 1y\implies C'=\frac 1y\implies C=c_1+\log(y)$$ Now, backwards $$C=c_1+\log(y)\implies u=\frac {c_1+\log(y)}y\implies z=\frac y{c_1+\log(y)}\implies x=\log\left(\frac y{c_1+\log(y)}\right)$$ Inversing the last leads to $$y=-e^x\, W\left(-e^{c_1-x}\right)$$ where appears Lambert function.

I suppose that some intermediate steps could have been avoided; but this is how I made it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Claude Leibovici!! Now it seems very easy. The main step was to use  $x=log (z) $. Fantastic idea.